# Multiple async functions at the same time with max workers

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust

I want to execute a list of async rust functions, but there should be a maximum of functions that can be executed at the same time. i tried it with spawns that will be awaited in multiple threads. I want that the result of the functions are pushed to a vector. Is that possible.

```
 let mut values = vec![sleeping(2), sleeping(1), sleeping(5), sleeping(7), sleeping(9), sleeping(2), sleeping(4), sleeping(1)];
    let mut handles = vec![];

    while !values.is_empty() {
        let mv = values.remove(0);
        handles.push( tokio::spawn(async move {
            mv.await
        }));
    }
    let rt = Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .worker_threads(4).build().unwrap();

    rt.block_on(async move {
        for handle in handles {
            handle.await.unwrap().expect("TODO: panic message");
        }
    });
```

Thats the error message i got from this attempt: Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.
thread 'tests::test_async' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Do you want a maximum number of tasks or a maximum number of threads on which the tasks will be executed?

Comment: it doenst really matter how it is implemented. I want that as soon as a function is completed it should execute the next one. I thought it would make sense to use multiple threads which operate seperatly from each other. As soon as one spawn is finished it should start with the next one until it is done.

Comment: You mean four threads/tasks that each execute the next task when they finished the previous, until all tasks are completed?

Comment: yes i have a list of tasks/spawns and there are always 4 functions awaited at the same time. When one finishes the next function starts without waiting for the other functions. So join_all couldnt be used

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works. It doenst use threads but works too:
`let u = stream::iter(sleep).map(|v| async move { v.await }).buffer_unordered(4);`

Comment: Note this will not run the futures _in parallel_, only _concurrently_.